# Trying to sum top 1 of subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is a small snippet of my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN I.IsSimCheckout=1 THEN 
    SUM(DISTINCT SalePrice) ELSE SUM(SalePrice) END 
FROM InvoiceDetail TD WHERE TD.InvoiceID = D.InvoiceID
```

What I am trying to do is this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN I.IsSimCheckout=1 THEN 
    SUM(TOP 1 SalePrice ORDER BY SalePrice) + SUM(TOP 1 SalePrice ORDER BY SalePrice DESC) ELSE SUM(SalePrice) END 
FROM InvoiceDetail TD WHERE TD.InvoiceID = D.InvoiceID
```

Obviously, I know the latter SQL won't compile. But basically, what I'm trying to do is, if I.IsSimCheckout is equal to 1, then I want to add the highest saleprice and the lowest saleprice together, rather then summing all of them together. Hopefully what I am trying to do makes sense and is clear.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Please review your question and give clear manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can this as below using groupby

```
  select 
  case when I.IsSimCheckout=1 then max(id.SalePrice)+min(id.SalePrice)
  else sum(id.SalePrice) as result
  from Invoice I join InvoiceDetail ID on I.InvoiceID=Id.InvoiceID
  group by i.InvoiceID, id.InvoiceID, I.IsSimCheckout
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
.... 
FROM InvoiceDetail TD
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 SalePrice
    FROM D(?)
    WHERE TD.InvoiceID = D.InvoiceID
    ORDER BY SalePrice ASC 
) LP
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 SalePrice
    FROM D(?)
    WHERE TD.InvoiceID = D.InvoiceID
   ORDER BY SalePrice DESC
) HP
 WHERE TD.InvoiceID = D.InvoiceID
```

This is the general idea. I'll leave the SELECT statement for you.